# Can't access shared folders or ping when on wifi

Tags: home-networking

My home network is:

Router: LinksysX3000

Machine1: Windows7Machine (this one is desktop and contains shared folders, connected to router via Ethernet cable)

Machine2: Windows10Machine (laptop, connected via wifi)

Machine3: MacOSxMachine (laptop, connected via wifi)

Machine2 & Machine3 can not access the shared folders on Machine1 nor can they ping it. Machine1 is just not visible to both at all. Neither can Machine1 ping the 2 machines. All 3 however can ping the router successfully.

If I connect Machine2 & Machine3 via Ethernet to the router, all machines can ping each othe and can access the shared folders on Machine1.

I have tried turning firewall off on all machines and the router but still same behaviour on wifi.

The wifi is password protected, mixed network mode, auto channel, wpa2 personal security mode.

Please let me know what your thoughts are on this?

further information:

- AP Isolation is disabled on router
- all machines on lan + wifi have same subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
- Machine1 has IP: 192.168.1.123 (ethernet)
- Machine2 has IP: 192.168.1.122 (ethernet)
- Machine2 has IP: 192.168.1.101 (when on wifi)
- Machine3 has IP: 192.168.1.115 (on wifi)

Comment: Have you checked that the WiFi devices are on the same subnet as when on Ethernet? And that your Wifi is not set up for Guest Access?

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the 3 machines (when 2 are connected by WiFi)?

Comment: Is your wireless configured in [Isolation Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/179089/lock-down-your-wi-fi-network-with-your-routers-wireless-isolation-option/)? "This feature confines and restricts clients connected to the Wi-Fi network. They can’t interact with devices connected to the more secure wired network, nor can they communicate with each other. They can only access the Internet."

Comment: subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 for all machines on lan + wifi, IP addresses are now provided in question in further information

Comment: Router's guest mode is off

Comment: @DavidPostill AP Isolation is disabled - for testing i just enabled and disabled again - did the reboot of router after disabling - still no luck

Comment: have you considered updating the firmware on the router? its certainly behaving like AP isolation is enabled.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes, updated to latest firmware yesterday - that didn't work either

Comment: Did updating the firmware reset the router to default settings/ If not, you might try resetting the router.